# Binary, hex, decimal comparison

Tags: java

I was playing a bit with numbers, and something interesting came upon me, which I don't quite understand.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         int hexNumber = 0x7A;//decimal: 122  binary:0111 1010
         int decNumber = 122;
         int binNumber = 1111010;

   System.out.println(hexNumber);//122
   System.out.println(Integer.toString(hexNumber, 16)); //7a
   System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(hexNumber));  //7a
   System.out.println(Integer.toString(hexNumber, 2)); //   1111010
   System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(hexNumber)); //1111010

   System.out.println(hexNumber==binNumber);//false
   System.out.println(hexNumber==decNumber);//true
   System.out.println(decNumber==binNumber);//false
    }
```

Why do I get "false" at #1 and #3? Doesn't change even if binNumber = 01111010;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can't directly store binary values in Java without any prefix.

`binNumber` isn't stored as the *binary* number `1111010`; instead, it's stored as the decimal number `1111010`.
This you have to store as `int binNumber = Integer.parseInt("1111010", 2);` or better yet `int binNumber = 0b1111010;`.

**For octal:**

`int octalNo = 0177; //'0' is prefix`

or

`int octalNo = Integer.parseInt("0177", 8); //leading '0's are ignored`

**For hexadecimal:**

`int hexNo = 0x177; //'0x' is prefix`

or

`int hexNo = Integer.parseInt("0177", 16); //leading '0's are ignored`

---

For more info, have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: Hm, I think I get it somehow. 1111010 is stored as 1.111.010, which is 1 million, actually. Then, how should I do it?

Comment: binary literals allowed in Java 7

Comment: @dkatzel Have a look now?

Comment: @ambigram_maker OK now

Answer (score 2):

You aren't creating the binary number as a binary one. You are creating it as a decimal one (base 10) that happens to only contain 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 2):

To store `0111 1010` in Java 7 use the new binary literal  (you can even use underscores for easier reading)

```
int binNumber = 0b0111_1010;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not the proper way to specify the binary number (and there is no such way in Java, apart from something like  `Integer.toBinaryString(122)` which would give you a proper binary representation (returned as a String)).

Your number was interpreted as a "normal" decimal integer (if entered without leading 0) or as an integer in octal system (if entered with leading 0).

Answer (score 0):

In Java versions before 7, you need to use this

```
int binNumber = Integer.parseInt("1111010", 2);
```

In 7 and up, you can use

```
int binNumber = 0b1111010;
```

With that change, your code works here (I get three true resuls).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clear. You have assigned to integers some diferent values.`hexNumber` is initialized to decimal value 122, even if the representation you use for that is hexadecimal. `decNumber` is initialized to decimal value 122, so when you compare `hexNumber` and `decNumber` you will get true because it's really the same value. Finally `binNumber` is initialized to the decimal value 1111010, so if you compare it with one of the other numbers you will get false.

Comment: Of couse this is because all the comparisons you are doing are being done with ints, that only stores decimal values